# Property 'sandwiches' does not exist on type 'string'

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to have an object that can contain strings or an array of strings. All with a string key. This is a config object that will be used in an app.

This object will be dynamic (user defined state values) so I have no way of specifying types based on the specific key name. Which is why I'm using index signatures as I don't know what the keys will be. I will be adding arrays from one part of my app, and strings from another part.

I'm getting errors as seen below:

[TS PLAYGROUND](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglgG2BATgZwMrAIbICrjQC8UA3gFBRQBmiy6AXGVANoDWEITawKcAdgHMAukwCCKFNhAAeHnyEA+KAB8o8gYKgBfcrvIBjAPb8eUCAA9sAWzAIITeElSYc+QlBIUqtZ4zKUVOrY-AAmAO5wBgAWEGhMLADk0TaJADRQiTEQcRCJwmmBVNaIbGgpHPGsWdFGBumZAEYhLfmFQVBSYUbWWAqCTMkQCAhG6YHahfoA9NNQ4dEgUAYhicBQwNFwaDRwggCuKNBG++tw68b7CKFQjdAhUNiS0gD85JY2dhAAdL70aN80CEIlFYgC-qgABTnCDWTzKGFwgCERBIyVSAEpyLMoIAZcnMkiMKCgJigvzoqAY2LmAAUUEZIChQJkIShElBQkY4lB+EZ1pZtutSaBIJkNEJVOpeJoWMJEt9qVA6QzUMzEqz2Zzubz+RZBST+BsPIlxYJEuRFZyoABJHk5G7AIxG0X8J708LmABuqBAwDg1mgjo52wMqENd2A4RyhtNjzCUv6srecGoUEhEikIG+2wz0khH1s9nJfgBQLCkWyaAxGICVALX2L-0BwIrYMbUMR8KgnZRaJS1kSWN0QA)

```
type FiltersStateType = {
  filters: { [key: string]: Array<string> | string }
}

const example: FiltersStateType = {
  filters: {
    sandwiches: ['ham', 'cheese'],
    milkshakes: ['choc', 'banana'],
    randomString: 'hello',
  },
}

example.filters.sandwiches.filter(item => item !== 'ham')
// ❌ Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'string | string[]'.
// ❌ Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'string'

// do I need to type narrow every time to discern between string and string[]?
if (Array.isArray(example.filters.sandwiches)) {
  example.filters.sandwiches.filter(item => item !== 'ham')
}
```

I presume this is because TS doesn't know if its a string or an Array. Do I need to type narrow every time to discern between string and string[]?

```
if (Array.isArray(example.filters.sandwiches)) {
  example.filters.sandwiches.filter(item => item !== 'ham')
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the behaviour would not be valid. You'd be able to call methods that dont exist. Maybe using an `instanceof` check would look nicer? Other than that there is little you can do as it needs to know what things are at runtime

Comment: Maybe if you elaborate on your usecase there is a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can recommend you to use this example. The line `[key: string]: Array<string> | string;` is for future properties which can be added in future. After I listed need properties and their types. The main problem is you can not combine several types and then access to property which is not included in both of types. For example I didn't list the `randomString` property but I can easily access to its n-th element because both of `array` and `string` has this property

```js
type FiltersStateType = {
  filters: {
    [key: string]: Array<string> | string;
    sandwiches: string[];
    milkshakes: string[];
  }
}

const example: FiltersStateType = {
  filters: {
    sandwiches: ['ham', 'cheese'],
    milkshakes: ['choc', 'banana'],
    randomString: 'hello',
  },
}

example.filters.sandwiches = example.filters.sandwiches.filter(item => item !== 'ham')

console.log(example.filters.sandwiches);
console.log(example.filters.randomString[1]);
```

Or you can use `as` keyword:

```js
type FiltersStateType = {
  filters: {
    [key: string]: Array<string> | string;
  }
}

const example: FiltersStateType = {
  filters: {
    sandwiches: ['ham', 'cheese'],
    milkshakes: ['choc', 'banana'],
    randomString: 'hello',
  },
}

example.filters.sandwiches = (example.filters.sandwiches as string[]).filter(item => item !== 'ham')

console.log(example.filters.sandwiches);
console.log(example.filters.randomString[1]);
```

Sorry in SO Code Snippet I can't run because of `as string[]`

Comment: Sorry I just updated the OP! The object is dynamic so I have no way of know the object key value. I only know that one part of my app will add arrays to it, and in another they will add strings. Thanks for the reply! 

Comment: I will update my answer :) 1 min pls

Comment: @HombreLobo I updated, my be it will helps you!

Comment: Oh that does help! So you are casting inside parenthesis before filtering! Cool! Thanks! It's a shame TS can't presume it can filter it, as it could be an Array...
Do you know how to solve issue 2? Thanks again! 

Comment: @HombreLobo did you delete second issue?

Comment: Sorry @eziomercer, I'm moving it to another question so that it is clearer and more helpful for others!

Comment: @HombreLobo can you please share link to second question and approve my answer here if it is not hard for you :) ?

Comment: Approved! And you found the other question! Thank you so much! :D

Comment: @HombreLobo Was happy to help!